# Normal form for a holomorphic Morse function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory

Similarly to Morse lemma, a holomorphic Morse function can be written, near a critical point, as $W_1^2+W_2^2+...+W_n^2+C$ , for well chosen coordinates $W_1,W_2,...,W_n$. I want to cite this result rather than write down the dull proof myself. Is there any well-written proof in the literature to cite ?

Comment: While not really an answer to your request for a reference, a standard (I think) observation is that the proof of the Morse lemma in Milnor's "Morse theory" adapts to the holomorphic case with only slight changes.

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion a good reference is the book by Greuel, Lossen and Shustin *Introduction to Singularities and Deformations*. See in particular Theorem 2.46, page 147. In fact, the authors prove the following more precise result.

> **Theorem (Morse Lemma).** Let $f \in \mathfrak{m}^2 \in \mathbb{C} \{x_1,\ldots ,x_n \}$ be a germ of holomorphic function, having a critical point at the origin $\mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{C}^n$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> **(1)** the point $\mathbf{0}$ is a non-degenerate critical point of $f$, i.e. the Hessian matrix  $H(f)(\mathbf{0})$ has maximal rank;
>
> **(2)** $\mu(f)=1$, where $\mu$ denotes the Milnor number;
>
> **(3)** $\tau(f)=1$, where $\tau$ denotes the Tjurina number;
>
> **(4)** $f$ is right equivalent to $x_1^2+ \ldots +x_n^2$;
>
> **(5)** $f$ is contact equivalent to $x_1^2+ \ldots +x_n^2$.

Note that the the statement you are looking for is precisely the equivalence between **(1)** and **(4)**.