# Is there a holomorphic Morse-Bott lemma?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, morse-theory

It asks for a generalization of the question in the post

[Normal form for a holomorphic Morse function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143598/normal-form-for-a-holomorphic-morse-function)

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on a complex manifold $M$ which has Bott type critical points, i.e., $df$ vanishes along a complex submanifold $S\subset M$ with nondegenerate Hessian in the normal direction to $S$. For each $p \in S$, can we find a holomorphic local coordinates $z_1, \ldots, z_s, z_{s+1}, \ldots, z_m$ such that locally

$$f(z_1, \ldots, z_m) = \sum_{j = s+1}^m z_j^2 + C,$$
where $s = {\rm dim} S$?

Answer (score 2):

**An invitation to Morse theory** is very good, but it can be a bit heavy. I managed to find [a very simple version of the lemma that is directly in the form you requested](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Sd1oaxfZ0lIC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=holomorphic+morse-bott+lemma&source=bl&ots=Gd3g3kVgBE&sig=UC2dipP5P-7uWtHU0JzBBctU7xk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7lWQU9XJLcWm4gSxnoBI&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) (I recently made use of this myself in my thesis).

It is a link to the PhD thesis of Matthew Petro, University of Wisconsin, from 2008. A preview is on available on google books, and the **Holomorphic Morse-Bott Lemma** is Lemma 3.8 in the text; the link should take you straight to it.

Out of curiosity, what are you using it for?

Comment: But this is simply stated in a thesis without proof, so it would behoove us to not accept this.

Comment: It should just be a restatement in different language. It is rigorously proved in multiple different texts but in more complicated language. Additionally, I would be very surprised if they let a PhD student simply state something like that in a successfully submitted thesis without proof or reference unless it was generally accepted to be true. My supervisor/external would have words to say if I did that.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate notion in the world of complex manifolds is the notion of a Lefschetz fibration on a Lefschetz pencil. To my knowledge, there is a nice exposition of the theory in

Liviu Nicolaescu, **An invitation to Morse theory**.

See Chapter 4 in the first edition of that book or Chapter 5 in the second edition. I think Theorem 4.3 or Theorem 5.3, resp., should be the result that you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't find anything related to my question.